# Excel to show icon

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I want to have icons that will signify increase, decrease or equal from the prior cell.
For example below in C2, the icon should increase when compared to B2 (because its value is greater). The comparison should always be made against the *prior* cell.

```
Col. A          Col. B     Col. C                                    
Thomas Moore        0        10
Albert Einstein    23        98
John Doe            8        50
```

Comment: okay look at this [Link](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/05/29/use-conditional-formatting-excel/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel conditional formatting icon sets will help you visually represent your data with arrows, shapes, check marks, flags, rating starts and other objects.

You apply the icon sets to your data by clicking Conditional Formatting > Icon Sets, and the icons appear inside selected cells straight away.

look at the following [Link](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/06/05/excel-conditional-formatting-icon-sets-data-bars-color-scales/)

Comment: thanks for the link..but I am still bit confused and getting incorrect results